# How to edit an xml attribute tag which is in a column in a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, xml, xml-parsing

This is a column XX from  a mySQL table . I need to change a value for one of the xml tags.

If i want to change the value to true in

```
<entry value="false" key="SaveColorSC"/>
```

how do i do that.. 
The table is called staff and column is called xx.??

```
<!DOCTYPE preferences SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd">
    <preferences EXTERNAL_XML_VERSION="1.0">
        <root type="user">
            <map/>
            <node name="xxx">
                <map/>
                <node name="user">
                    <map/>
                    <node name="admin">
                        <map>
                            <entry value="DICOM" key="ImportDestination"/>
                           ...
                            <entry value="false" key="SaveColorSC"/>
                            <entry value="-256" key="GSPSColor"/>
                            <entry value="-16711936" key="SelectedAnnotationColor"/>
                            <entry value="1" key="MeasurementType"/>
                            <entry value="false" key="ChangeMeasurementTypeAfterCanc
    el"/>






Please help !

Thanks a lot !!
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: This is the first time am using MySQL and i tried  UPDATE Staff
    -> SET preferences('replace value of (/root//entry[@value="DICOM"]/@key)[1] with sql:variable("@new")')' with @new INT = 50